# The length of Triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is the length of a e ?

I tried to prove that the triangle aeb is similar to ced with head angles (e for both triangles) and the proportional sides (ab and cd) but still need to prove two angles are equal.

Comment: Are CD and AB parallel?

Comment: Use Pythagoras and Thales Theorems.

Comment: What do you know about the angles $dcb$ and $abc$?

Comment: yes, AB and CD are Parallel.

Comment: Emilio Novati, these angles are 90 degrees

Answer (score 1):

Use Pythagoras Theorems
$$AC^2=AB^2+BC^2=2^2+4^2=20$$
$$AC=2\sqrt5$$
Use Thales Theorems:

$$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AB}{CD}=\frac24=\frac12$$
Hence, $$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac12$$
and $$AE+EC=AC=2\sqrt5$$
Let $AE=x, EC=2x$

Thus, $$x+2x=2\sqrt5$$
$$3x=2\sqrt5$$
$$x=\frac{2\sqrt5}3$$

$$AE=\frac{2\sqrt5}3$$

Comment: I could not understand what you did in Thales Theorems, the triangles are not similar.

Comment: If $AB||CD$ then the triangles $ABE$ and $CDE$ are similar

Comment: but why are you using AC proportional to CD?

Comment: @user3188039: I edited

Comment: Still not clear how you got the final answer, we don't have any relationship between AC and any other side.

Comment: @user3188039: I edited